# KVM raw disk has comparable write, slow read

Tags: kvm-virtualization, raw-disk

I first ran
fio tests, and apparently my write speed is basically 90%, but my read speed is 40%.
Here is my xml file:

```
<emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
  <source file='/mnt/raid_array/test_server/ubuntu20.04'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'>
</disk>
```

Fio:

> fio --name=seqread --rw=read --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --bs=1024k --numjobs=8 --size=1G --runtime=600  --group_reporting  (sequential read)

Host: 327MB/s
VM: 127MB/s This is only 39% of the Host speed.

> fio --name=seqwrite --rw=write --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --bs=1024k --numjobs=8 --size=2G --runtime=600 --group_reporting

Host:141MB/s VM: 114MB/s This is 80 percent of the host speed. This is acceptable, but I would like this to be higher too.

I am running BTRS raid 1, does anyone have any tips for speeding up my read speed?

Comment: What tests? What storage backs this? fio command line?  Results distributions resumed, IOPS and throughput? What performance did you expect?

Comment: Fio. BTRFS raid 1. Yes. IOPS and etc to be posted. Performance 80% + of host speed.

Comment: @JohnMahowald I added Sequential Read and Write Resuts.